# String to specify to KUBE_SERVICE_ADDRESSES (API Server configuration)

Tags: kubernetes, configuration

What are the strings to set to `KUBE_SERVICE_ADDRESSES` and their meanings? Which documentation or GitHub repo to look into to understand?

Background: I have seen a few strings but not sure what these strings mean. Such as:

```
KUBE_SERVICE_ADDRESSES="--portal_net=10.254.0.0/16"
KUBE_SERVICE_ADDRESSES="--service-cluster-ip-range=10.254.0.0/16"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this Q&A](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/9040) and [this code](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/96fecb2833c47b75267581cc4587a653f364268e/cluster/centos/master/scripts/apiserver.sh#L61) the `--portal_net` was renamed to `--service-cluster-ip-range` since version 0.18.

> ```
> # --service-cluster-ip-range=<nil>: A CIDR notation IP range from which to assign service cluster IPs.
> # This must not overlap with any IP ranges assigned to nodes for pods.
> KUBE_SERVICE_ADDRESSES="--service-cluster-ip-range=${SERVICE_CLUSTER_IP_RANGE}"
> ```